# Customizing Step Indicator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I create this step indicator using `react-native-step-indicator`

[image]

I want to customize the labels inside the indicator to show symbols instead of numbers, similar to this image:

[image]

I have tried various approaches but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Below is my current code:

```
  <StepIndicator
            stepCount={getStepsData?.getSteps?.length}
            customStyles={styles.customStyles}
            currentPosition={activePosition}
            direction="vertical"
            labels={getStepsData?.getSteps?.map((step) => step.name)}
            onPress={(position) => setActivePosition(position)}
            renderLabel={({ position, stepStatus, label, currentPosition }) => {
              return (
                <View key={position}>
                  <Text style={position === activePosition ? styles.pressedTitle : styles.title}>{getStepsData?.getSteps[position].name}</Text>
                  {position === activePosition &&
                    <Text style={styles.stepDescription}>{getStepsData?.getSteps[position].description}</Text>
                  }
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Custom Styles:

```
customStyles: {
        stepIndicatorSize: 30,
        labelAlign: 'flex-start',
        currentStepIndicatorSize: 40,
        separatorStrokeWidth: 3,
        currentStepStrokeWidth: 5,
        stepStrokeCurrentColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        separatorFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        separatorUnFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        stepIndicatorFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        stepIndicatorCurrentColor: Colors.white,
        stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
        currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
        stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#000000',
        stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: Colors.white,
        stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: Colors.white,
        labelColor: Colors.DarkSlate,
        labelSize: 15,
        currentStepLabelColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
    },
```

Comment: Start by looking at the examples on the [github](https://github.com/24ark/react-native-step-indicator) for that library.  There is a shopping cart checkout example that uses icons.